# Injecting javascript into android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Good evening. I want to click on button by JS in WebView. This code works in chrome console

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click();
```

So, I'm trying to do the same in android

```
WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    Intent webIntent = getIntent();
    String url = webIntent.getStringExtra("url");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click(); })()");
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

And I have an Unknown chromium error: -324 in LogCat. What can be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click();");
```